# Saving Exported doc file to the disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, export

Is it possible to save an exported word document file using Response.Write(). Now it's showing Save/Open dialog box, once it Converted successfully. But i need to save this file to a folder. Please help me for resolve this issue.

My conversion to Doc code is appended below.

```
  private void ExportDataSetToWordDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".doc"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            tblMain.RenderControl(htw);


            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {

            Common.LogError(ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can't control where the browser saves the file. If you could, imagine how much fun malware could have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified my code as shown below. Now its saving the specified folder

```
Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".doc"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            tblMain.RenderControl(htw);

            string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Test.doc";
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(strPath);
            sWriter.Write(sw.ToString());
            sWriter.Close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the Browser to offer the user an "open or save" option.  That's what your content-disposition "attach" is encouraging the browser to do.  Your other option is content-disposition "inline", where the browser will usually just call up the application (Word in this case) to open the file.  [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition.inline.aspx).

Sadly, the browser will not always offer the filename you specified as the default filename in the "Save As" dialog.  Often it will offer the name of your web page as the default instead.  Firefox at least documents this as a bug, IE seems to think it is a "feature".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stream writer (System.IO.StreamWriter) using a path.
When the stream writer will be closed, the file will be saved on at the specified path.

But, it will save on the server disk. If you want to save on the client side, you don't have other choice than ask the user where to put the file. You can't save files on a client without its approval.

```
var x = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
x.Close();
```